# Pyplot doesn't compile LaTeX code at all, although it knows a valid MikTeX installation

Tags: python, matplotlib, miktex

I want to have text rendering with Latex for titles, labels, etc. of plots.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show, xlabel, ylabel, legend, title
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata = array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
ydata = array([1, 8, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 16])
plot(xdata, ydata, 'x')

plt.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\usepackage{amsmath}'
plt.title(r'$\alpha$')
show()
```

A basic requirement would be a Greek letter, like shown in the above code in my opinion.
The result is not a rendered symbol, but just the plain text I entered.

I know I have a valid MikTex distribution, with path set correctly.
I tried a few things like doubled dollar signs `$$`, or `import amsmath`.

When I produce an invalid Latex code like unclosed math mode/uneven number of dollar signs, I can see at the console that MikTeX is involved and throws an error. So it seems to be installed correctly, and to be known by the Pycharm IDE or so. But at the end of the day, it doesn't compile a single expression.

Comment: I don't think you need the `plt.rcParams` lines in your code.  Strangely, when I run your code, I don't get a title the first time I call plt.show(), but if I set the title again and repeat the plt.show(), I do get the correct title.  Not quite sure what's going on.

Comment: When I tested the code, it functions as is (but also when the rcParams are removed) as mentioned by @FrankYellin.  Could you add the error you're getting? It's likely something install-wise.

Comment: I reinstalled MikTeX, but now I get the error
Another MiKTeX program has exclusevily locked the package database.
Close running MiKTeX programs and try again.

Comment: Ok, now MikTeX is properly installed. The Skript runs without an error. But the title shows just the plain text (the initial problem persists).